# Obfuscating key fields in mySql dump file to protect privacy

Tags: java, mysql, obfuscation, dump

I am looking for ways to obfuscate the MySql database dump file for some key fields in some tables to protect the data privacy before sharing the dump file with other developers.
What are the simplest ways to do it?  we are looking at some way of modifying the dump sql file before restoring it to the database.
Any tool or any well known way to solve this problem?
One issue to consider is to keep the length of the values same to avoid any data overflow.

Comment: What programming tools do you have at your disposal? Python, Ruby, Node.js, Perl, even C# or Java could do this.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that..preferred is Java

Comment: One way is to dump it out as CSV, mangle the contents using a script, then roll it back in later using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Do you have a fake data generator library that can stomp the original values? I use [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) in Ruby and there's analogs in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

[ProxySQL](http://www.proxysql.com/) supports obfuscating data and also supports doing so with exports made by mysqldump. It is better used at the time you do the data dump however.